# Procedure returns error: Cannot cast System.Int32 to System.Int32[]

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I wrote a procedure that is supposed to return a value from my database.  The value to be returned is an integer. Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub btnSelectProducts_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectProducts.Click

    Try

    'Connection Variables
    Dim cnn As SqlCeConnection
    Dim connectionString As String

    'Connect to database
    connectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\ContactsAndInventory.sdf"
    cnn = New SqlCeConnection(connectionString)

    Dim Stream As New MemoryStream()
    cnn.Open()

    Dim command As New SqlCeCommand("SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORY WHERE (CATEGORY_NAME = @CATEGORY_NAME)", cnn)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY_NAME", txtCategoryName.Text)

        Dim catId As Integer() = CType(command.ExecuteScalar(), Integer())'Error Here

    MsgBox(catId)

        cnn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try


End Sub
```

I am getting the error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast objct to type System.Int32 to type System.Int32[]
```

In can't figure out why, the field is an Integer field and the value I am trying to return is an integer.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Dim catId As Integer()` is an Array of Integers, leave of the `()` and it would have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out my error:

```
  Dim catId = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar())
```